# unserializing data array with php from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I have the following serialized PHP array stored in a mySQL database:

```
a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";}
```

Now, I managed to output that value with:

```
$my_data=mysql_result($result,$i,"my_data");
echo "$my_data";
```

but I can't manage to unserialize it. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$my_data=unserialize($my_data);
```

When I add that in between, all I get is a blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you turned on display_errors? Or looked into your error logs. A blank screen often indicates some kind of error.

Comment: I just tried that and get this: Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 12 of 62 bytes in test.php on line 25

Comment: Have you checked the string returned from the db is identical to the string you put into the db? btw it's not usually considered good practice to store a serialised string in a db.

Comment: and var_dump shows bool(false)

Comment: Yeah, the string is the same. Unfortunately my software developer did it that way, not me :( I tested the serialized string on unserialize.net and it decoded it fine there, so I figure the problem must be on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should look at the process of inserting the the value into the database. Is it possible that after the values are serialized, that they were encoded in someway, such as to html entities or something?

I ran a test locally and I got the same error message. Here is output:

```
a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";} Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 12 of 62 bytes in /srv/localhost/public_html/test.php on line 6
```

Here is code

```
<?php

$value = htmlentities('a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";}');
echo $value;

unserialize($value);
```

Comment: that was the problem! The " was converted into HTML tags. I replaced them and now it works!